# How can I split a word's letters, with each last four letters in a line?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

How can I split a word's letters and in between one single space, with each last four letters in a line?
For example, 
Given,

```
 1. placing
 2. backtick
 3. paragraphs
```

I would like to see in below

```
 1. pla cing
 2. back tick
 3. pa ragr aphs
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl (and assuming single-byte characters only):

```
perl -ne 'print scalar(reverse join " ", (reverse =~ /.{1,4}/g)), "\n"'
```

- The inner `reverse` will reverse the given word (in fact, the whole input line, regardless of what it contains).
- The regular expression will chop the reversed word up into chunks of four characters (the last chunk, from the beginning of the original word, may contain fewer characters).
- The `join` will join these chunks into a string, but with spaces in-between.
- The outer `reverse` reverses the joined string.
- The `scalar` is used to force the outer `reverse` to operate in scalar context.
- The `print` will output the result.

The code below does the same thing, but does away with `scalar`, `"\n"` and `print` by using `-p`, `-l` and assigning to `$_`:

```
perl -lpe '$_ = reverse join " ", reverse =~ /.{1,4}/g'
```

Comment: unfortunately, this approach breaks the last line (dot `.` shifting) https://ibb.co/ga1kWa

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I'm not quite sure I understand.

Comment: @Kusalananda, look again to my screenshot (last line, dot `.` position)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest The digit, dot and space is part of the input?

Comment: @Kusalananda, I suppose, yes, as they figure in the expected output

Comment: @Kusalananda You should not the reversing the whole line, but rather the last field only: `perl -pale '$_ = $F[0] . $" . reverse join $", reverse($F[1]) =~ /.{1,4}/g'`

Comment: @RakeshSharma My view is that my solution is correct, but that there might be a need for pre- and post-processing. The Perl command should only be applied to the word after the space, so a simple `cut -d ' ' -f2` serves as a pre-processing step. The processed words may be merged with the original numbers through `cut` and `paste` as a post-processing step.

Comment: Actually, `-Mopen=locale` wouldn't work as `reverse` reverses byte-wise, not character wise. I'll delete that comment.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`, you could do something like:

```
sed '
  G
  :1
      s/\([[:alpha:]]\)\([[:alpha:]]\{4\}\)\(\n\)/\1\3 \2/
  t1
  s/\n//
'
```

We use a newline character as a running marker (newline is the one character that won't appear inside the initial pattern space). We add it at the end initially. Then as long as we find `ABCDE<marker>` (where ABCDE are 5 alphabetic characters, you can replace `[[:space:]]` with `[^[:blank:]]` if you want to consider words as sequences of non-blanks as opposed to sequences of letters), we replace it with `A<marker> BCDE` and loop. And we remove the marker in the end.

That way, we're sure to process only the word that is at the end of the line only.

If you wanted to break down every word, not just the last word that way, it would be simpler:

```
sed -e :1 -e 's/\(.*[[:alpha:]]\)\([[:alpha:]]\{4\}\)/\1 \2/;t1'
```

If your input contains decomposed characters (like in the output of `printf 'abcd\u00e9e\u0301f\n'`: `abcdééf`), you could do:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -lpe 'while(s/.*(?=\w)\X\K(?:(?=\w)\X){4}/ $&/){}'
```

Comment: You should simply say `G` instead of the `s/$/\`

Answer (score 1):

**awk** solution:

```
awk '{ c=0; for(i=length($2);i>0;i-=4) {a[++c]=(i-4>0)? substr($2,i-4+1,4) : substr($2,1,i)} 
    $2=""; for(i=length(a);i>0;i--) $2=$2 FS a[i] }1' file
```

The output:

```
1.  pla cing
2.  back tick
3.  pa ragr aphs
```

Answer (score 1):

With `Perl` using `lookarounds` we could perform the operation as:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=\w)(?=(?:\w{4})+$)/ /g'
```

Which translates as: when standing at a position, to our left is an alphanumeric and to our right are at least 4 alnums or multiples thereof
right to the end of the string. Whenver such a position exists, a space is
placed there. Doing this globally effects the change requested.

We could use `bash` to do this as well:

```
#!/bin/bash

# symbolic constants
NL=$'\012'; # newline
SP=$'\040'; # space

# elementary regexes
alnum='[0-9a-zA-Z]'; # a single alphanumeric
alnums4=$(csh -c 'repeat 4 echo -n "$1"' "$alnum"); # 4 consecutive alnums

# main processing
while IFS= read -r line res; do
   while c4=$(expr "$SP$line$NL" : ".*$alnum\($alnums4\)$NL")
   do
      res=${c4}${res:+"$SP"}${res-} line=${line%????}
   done
   printf '%s %s\n' "$line" "$res"
done
```

Using the `GNU sed` editor:

```
sed -Ee '
   s/\S+/\n&\n/2; # enclose the 2nd field with markers

   # a do-while loop to progessively move the right marker to the left,
   # consuming 4 alnums in each iteration. Looping stops when 4 alnums+
   # 1 alnum at the boundary remains.
   :loop
      s/(\n[[:alnum:]].*)([[:alnum:]]{4})\n/\1\n \2/
   tloop

   # clear out the markers when done
   s/\n//g
'
```